# I have a VB.NET application with a transparent form. Any control on that form appears to be read-only. Any idea why?

Tags: vb.net, controls, transparent

Ok.  A bit more detail.

I have been tasked with producing a piece of software that overlays technical data from our in-house systems, onto the desktop depending on user id.  Extracting the data and mapping it by user id is already done, but the display part is where i'm stuck.

I read a post (and watched a video) where the background of the form was set to a specific colour, with the transparency_key set to the same colour, and the border style set to none.  This makes it transparent and any control placed on that form should appear to float.

Unfortunately, if I attempt to programattically alter any of these controls, nothing happens.  for example, I have a 5000ms timer.  Per tick, it writes the word "tick" to the console, and changes label1.text to the current time.

```
console.writeline("Tick")
label1.text = datetime.now.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

When I run in debug mode (or after a publish) all I get is the default "label1" text of the label.

Also, I've programatically told the software to change the forecolor to red.  It remains black.

```
Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Has anyone else encountered this, and how did they get around it please?

Comment: does it work as expected without the transparency trick? do you highjack the desktop hwnd, or is it an overlay? windows forms?

Comment: Which Timer are you using?

Comment: WHat happens when you put a breakpoint in the timer function

Comment: This sounds like you are not updating the control you think you are.  Are you using the default (devil spawn) Form instance?  Show a bit more code.

Comment: ANd it should work that way... so either the timer is not running, or something else you are doing is locking the UI